# Regex don't consider spaces

Tags: regex

I want to find n consecutive numbers in a text. I can't just allow space because that would break the count rule (n digits!). What would be the easiest way to do this?

I mean I don't want to do
`\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*`... etc I feel there's a better way.

edit: `[\d\s]{n}` doesn't work because I want n digits not n characters.

Comment: Would this work for you? `[0-9 ]+`

Comment: What's the `n` rule? `[\d\h]+` should work (depending on where the regex is used, and if you want to allow tabs as well) although that wouldn't require a number.. probably a safer approach is `\d[\d\h]*` which is a number then any number of spaces/tabs and numbers.

Comment: @DaanMeijer sounds like the pattern needs to match `n` digits (with or without spaces intermixed). I'm assuming that's what the "n rule" is, anyway...

Comment: Yes I updated it to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: You mean you to allow a fixed number of numbers, regardless of how many spaces there are? I'd strip all whitespace, and use a `string length` and `is numeric` function in what ever language you are using.

Comment: So if `n` = 3 you'd want to match `123` but not `1234`? How about `(?:^|\D)\d{3}(?:$|\D)`?

Comment: @EralpB Can you please give concrete examples of valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: `var nums = text.match(/\d+/g); if (nums && nums.length == n) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @Guedes a) not sure if we can assume this is a JavaScript question, and b) that still forces the digits to be consecutive (no intermixed whitespace supported).

Comment: @chris85 yes that's the practical approach. But I wanted to know the regexful way of doing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

`/^\s*(?:\d\s*){n}$/`

Explanation:

- `/^\s*…$` will match a string that optionally begins with whitespace.
- `(?:…){n}` creates a non-capturing group, where everything in the group will be matched `n` times.
- `\d\s*` will match a single digit, with optional whitespace after it.

Comment: Avoid the `\s*` both at begging and end of the repeating groups as it might cause exponential back tracking in case of incorrect input. The following is a better alternative: `/^\s*(?:\d\s*){n}$/

Comment: @jwatkins great catch! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This requires exactly n digits:

```
^\D*(\d\D*){n}\D*$
```

or if only spaces are allowed other than digits:

```
^ *(\d ){n} *$
```